# Implied Volatility, % Change in the Option Chain

Tags: call-options, option-strategies

The following is the Options Chain of **CRM (Salesforce)** for March 19, 2021.

A few questions from the chart:

1. What does the **% Change** mean in this chart?
2. What does the **Volume** mean?
3. At the $300 strike, I see 4899 **Open Internet**. Does that mean 4899 options have been sold by traders who are expecting the price to reach at $300?
4. Is there any indication from the chart that the **IV** will not go down significantly for CRM before March 19, 2021 from the current level of 39%?
5. What is the right option strategy for any stock symbol to play against the IV but only against the price?
6. Take this scenario. A trader buy at strike at $115 at IV 71.95%. A month from now, IV drops to 25% but the price goes up to $240. Does that make a profit or a loss?
7. From the Chart what is considered as a **low IV**? Is 40$ low IV?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does the % Change mean in this chart?

Percent change from close to close

> What does the Volume mean?

Number of contracts traded

> At the $300 strike, I see 4899 Open Internet. Does that mean 4899 options have been sold by traders who are expecting the price to reach at $300?

Buyers expect calls to rise not sellers

> Is there any indication from the chart that the IV will not go down significantly for CRM before March 19, 2021 from the current level of 39%?

Option chains do not predict future IV

> What is the right option strategy for any stock symbol to play against the IV but only against the price?

Unclear question.

> Take this scenario. A trader buy at strike at $115 at IV 71.95%. A month from now, IV drops to 25% but the price goes up to $240. Does that make a profit or a loss?

Learn to use an option pricing model.

> From the Chart what is considered as a low IV? Is 40$ low IV?

Go to IVolatility and look at a one year chart of CRM's IV.  From that, determine what you think high and low IV are for CRM.